# how to assign an intent content to to an already created textview in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am an beginner in Android development. I Have created a main activity and a second activity. The main activity contains an edittext and a button. The second activity contains some textviews. I have to display the content of the edittext in one of the textviews (eg:textview1) along with a Welcome message. Other textviews in the second activity displays text I have entered in the second activity xml code.

My java code for the second activity is this

```
Intent intent = getIntent()
String message = intent.getStringExtra(Main Activity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
text.setText(message);
```

when running this I am getting an error. Please help

Comment: Please post the o/p of LogCat.

Comment: @arisepeter Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below code in second activity

```
Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
String message = bdl.getString("data");
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
text.setText(message);
```

instead of

```
Intent intent = getIntent()
String message = intent.getStringExtra(Main Activity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
text.setText(message);
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: I did as you said and defined a new bundle Bundle bdl= new Bundle(); but how to pass the value of my edittext "edittext1" to the bundle? pls explain

Comment: @arisepeter Define bundle in second activity for getting data and pass value in intent to pass data in first activity.

Answer (score 1):

Use like

For **First Activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("data",ed.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

For **Second Activity**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra("data");
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
text.setText(message);
```

Don't forget to define **Activity** in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

in First Activity you have to write

```
Intent i = new Intent(Act1.this , Act2.class);
Bundle b= new Bundle();
b.putString("key" , String);
i.putExtras(b);
StartActivity(i);
```

In Second Acitivity onCreate you can write

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String Text = b.getString("key");
Textview txt = (Textview) findViewById(R.id.txt);
txt.setText(Text);
```

This way you can pass one activity to another activity

(vatsalshah.co.in)

Comment: finally my problem solved.  we have to give set content view in the second activity as follows                                                                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);